# Having trouble creating a PHP script for my android jogging app

Tags: php, android, mysql

For the past 2 weeks I've been developing my jogging application and i'm trying to set up a Login/signup screen that uses PHP to store the information into MYSQL, I've tried implementing dozens of PHP login/sign up screens and i have had no luck, my application crashes every time i run it and attempt to type information in for sign up before logging in, i know this is due to my PHP script not configured correctly, can anyone help me develop one, it would be greatly appreciated, here is my code.

```
public class signsignupview extends Activity {
private ImageButton settingHomeNav;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SharedPreferences to save user name and password
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String namekey = "nameKey";
public static final String passkey = "passwordKey";
public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Progress Dialog Bar
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sign up fields
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EditText username2;
EditText password2;
EditText emailfill;
EditText addressfill;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// URL to connect to PHP files for Sign up and Login
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static String rootURL = "http://www.example.com/";
private static String url_sign_up = rootURL + "insert.php";
private static String url_sign = rootURL + "getlist.php";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Login fields"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EditText emailsignin;
EditText password;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// JSON node name
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signsignup);

    username2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username2);
    password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    emailfill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailfill);
    addressfill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressfill);

    emailsignin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data persistence
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(namekey))
    {
        if(sharedpreferences.contains(passkey)){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Home button
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    settingHomeNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeImageButton);
    settingHomeNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sign up button
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Button btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create a new function to run in background thread while Signing up
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Home button
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Button btn_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create a new function to run in background thread while Logging in
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            new createSignIn().execute();
        }
    });
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Background Async Task for user Log in
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class createSignIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String > {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(signsignupview.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Signing In ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String email = emailsignin.getText().toString();
        String passwd = password.getText().toString();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Building Parameters
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwd));

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Getting JSON Object
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sign,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check for success tag
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Login successful
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                editor.putString(namekey, email);
                editor.putString(passkey, passwd);
                editor.commit();

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Launching Home activity
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message - "Username/Password Incorrect !"
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username/Password Incorrect !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Background Async Task for user Sign up
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String > {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(signsignupview.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Signing Up..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = username2.getText().toString();
        String password = password2.getText().toString();
        String email = emailfill.getText().toString();
        String city = addressfill.getText().toString();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Building Parameters
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Getting JSON Object
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sign_up,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check for success tag
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message as success and prompt the user to log in
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Created Successfully. Please Login now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Display Toast message as failure
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Handler handler =  new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                handler.post( new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to create User.Please check entries",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.d("sign up ","failed");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Funtion to clear the user sign up form
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.signsignupview);
        clearForm(group);
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clear the user sign up form
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void clearForm(ViewGroup group)
{
    for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)view).setText("");
        }
        if(view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0))
            clearForm((ViewGroup)view);
    }
}
}
```

PHP script for signing in:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("dbhost","username","password", "dbname") or die(mysqli_error($connection));



if(isset($_POST['tag']))
{          
if($_POST['tag']=="success")
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $strSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"select name from users where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'");
    $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL);
    if(count($Results)>=1)
    {
        $message = $Results['name']." Login Sucessfully!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Invalid email or password!!";
    }        
}

}


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

This is the logcat error message i get:

04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.runforlife.GPSRunner.signsignupview has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{131e5078 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at com.runforlife.GPSRunner.signsignupview$createSignIn.onPreExecute(signsignupview.java:177)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at com.runforlife.GPSRunner.signsignupview$3.onClick(signsignupview.java:157)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5256)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
04-15 18:46:48.923: E/WindowManager(5590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

Comment: What does you java code have to do with PHP?

Comment: I want to store my login details after entering in some details from signing up a new user in a sql database and then i want to grab that information to login

Comment: Would it not be more useful to see the PHP code that is crashing?  Then maybe I can see how it ties together.

Comment: Yeah sure, i have added my PHP script for logging in, the signup one is more or less identical to my loggin in script but i can add that too

Comment: Please add the exact errors you are getting when your app crashes

Comment: I'm using android studio and they are no errors on the android studio side, my application doesn't crash when i try to sign in, it just stops, it comes up with the message on my phone unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: @kiddkidd if you are getting the *Unfortunately app has stopped* message, then you need to check your logcat output in android studio. There will be error messages there that tell you what is going wrong. http://i.imgur.com/SGGTLQq.png

Comment: does android studio have logcat?

Comment: Okay i have not put the logcat error message up in my question above